# values not correctly rendered in line chart in extjs?

Tags: extjs, charts, draw, extjs4

I'm having trouble with result rendered by [line chart](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/charts/Charts.html) example from extjs4
the columns are rendered correctly but the line is not, notice in the picture how i need to have 4 while its drawed in the 0 xpoint also the second plot is supposed to be 5 when its draw in 2:
[image]
here is my code:

```
 panel3 = Ext.create('widget.panel', {

    width: 600,
    height: 200,
    frame: false,
    renderTo: 'line',
    layout: 'fit',
    items: {
        xtype: 'chart',
        animate: false,
        store: storeline,
        insetPadding: 20,
        gradients: [{
            angle: 90,
            id: 'bar-gradient',
            stops: {
                0: {
                    color: '#99BBE8'//C12283
                },
                70: {
                    color: '#77AECE'
                },
                100: {
                    color: '#77AECE'
                }
            }
        }],
        axes: [{
            type: 'Numeric',
            minimum: 0,
            maximum: 10,
            position: 'left',
            fields: ['data1'],
            title: false,
            grid: true,
            label: {
                renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0,0'),
                font: '10px Arial'
            }
        }, {
            type: 'Category',
            position: 'bottom',
            fields: ['name'],
            title: false,
            grid: true,
            label: {
                font: '11px Arial',
                rotate: {
                    degrees: 300
                }
            }
        }],
        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            axis: 'left',
            xField: 'name',
            yField: 'data1',
                display: 'over',
            style: {
                fill: 'url(#bar-gradient)',
                'stroke-width': 30
            }  ,
            markerConfig: {
                type: 'circle',
                size: 4,
                radius: 4,
                'stroke-width': 20,
                fill: '#38FFFF',
                stroke: '#38B8BF'
            }
        },
        {
            type: 'line',
            axis: 'left',
            xField: 'name',
            yField: 'data2',
            tips: {
                trackMouse: true,
                width: 110,
                height: 25,
                //baseCls: 'customtip', //bodyStyle: 'background:#6cc; ',
                renderer: function (storeItem, item) {
                    this.setTitle(storeItem.get('name') + ' : ' + storeItem.get('data2'));
                }
            },
            style: {
                fill: '#18428E',
                stroke: '#18428E',
                'stroke-width': 3
            },
            markerConfig: {
                type: 'circle',
                size: 5,
                radius: 5,
                'stroke-width': 0,
                fill: '#18428E',
                stroke: '#18428E'
            }
        }]
    }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your axis definition try changing

```
fields: ['data1'],
```

to

```
fields: ['data1', 'data2'],
```

Also verify that the data being loaded into the data2 field is an actual integer. ExtJs might be reading it as a string and therefore is unable to match it with a value on the left axis.

Comment: IF you look at the line chart example [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/charts/Line.html), you can see that the field property in the axis definition contains the names of all the fields that are bound to that axis. That is why I suggested it. However, I think that's trivial. I was able to reproduce your issue by changing the data type of one of those fields to be a string so I think the problem is in your store definition.

Comment: thats not the example im using, in the one u pointed they have two lines i only have and need one. for ur other suggestion,i cant try it now im off work i'll have to wait untill monday, the problem is that my data is double at first but then i serelize it to json ,in json its all string and yet the columns are dispalyed ok..so im not sure how can i change this

Comment: You should be able to specify the data types of each field in your store definition.It actually might be helpful if you posted your store definition here as well.

Comment: `storeline = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
        fields: ['name', 'data1', 'data2'],
        data: Ext.decode(obj.ToJson())
    });`

Comment: And have you tried specifying the data2 field as an int. 'storeline = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', { 
    fields: ['name', 'data1', {name: 'data2', type: 'int'}], 
    data: Ext.decode(obj.ToJson()) 
});'

Comment: another question if possible..do u know how to fix the width of the columns as u see they r very large since there is only two displayed.thx

Comment: To decrease the size of the columns then you'll have to decrease the size of the parent panel. Ext will generate the column width based on the number of columns and available size therefore there is no actual width property for a column. You might be able to artificially alter the width by setting a high gutter value but this is really just a workaround. For example, add the following to your column series definition and see how it looks -  gutter: 100.00

Comment: IF you are interested I would look at the getBarGirth function in ext-all-debug as this is the method that calculates the actual width of the column

Comment: if its not too much asking,that would be nice, as the nbr of columns is dynamic so i cant just decrease the panel's width and gutter doesnt work when its only one column. if ur going to look,do u want me to ask a question about it?

Comment: lol I actually meant for you to have a look at that method but on re-reading my comment I can see where the confusion comes from. I don't really have the time to investigate this further but you should look at doing the following: 1. Create your own chart component which inherits from the Ext.chart.series.Column class. 2. This class would override the getBarGirth method allowing it take a config width option. If a width is not passed through then the code should function as normal. I hope this helps.

Comment: lol. im very new to this , i dont think i can but would try,thanks